# how to write the output of array in special format in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"Dog","b"=>"Cat","c"=>"Horse");
print_r($a);
?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [a] => Dog [b] => Cat [c] => Horse )
```

Which format  i want is

```
[a] => Dog ;
[b] => Cat;
[c] => Horse;
```

1.There is no  **Array ()** in the outpur.
2.every elements of Array + **；** in one line.

How to write the print command in php?

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Loop through the array and print it however you need. Using the built-in print construct limits you to that specific style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo '['. $key . '] => '. $value. ';<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "My key: $key, my value: $value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>;
```

This should get you close.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the array using `foreach` and print it

```
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
   echo "[{$key}] = {$value} <br>";
}
```